# Packing JFrame according to actual JPanel, not the parent

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I am starting with `Java Swing` for a second day. I have come across the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) briefly explaining the approach with multiple `JFrame` is not recommended. According the answer I started to explore the way using `CardLayout`.

My trouble is when I call `pack()` of the only and main `JFrame`, it packs automatically according the main `JPanel`, that contains the `CardLayout` of several `JPanels` created in the Netbeans GUI and not according to actual chosen `JPanel` I wish to.

Here is an overview of my main class `Main`:

```
private static String[] PANELS = {"A", "B"};
private static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new Main().initialize();
        }
    });
}

public void initialize() {

    JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    JPanelA a = new JPanelA(cards);
    cards.add(a, PANELS[0]);

    Main.frame = new JFrame("GUI example");
    Main.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Main.frame.add(cards);
    Main.frame.pack();
    Main.frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    Main.frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanelB b = new JPanelB(cards);
    cards.add(b, PANELS[1]);
}   

public static JFrame getFrame() {
    return Main.frame;
}

public static String getPanel(int i) {
    return PANELS[i];
}
```

Each JPanel is created in the NetBeans GUI, having the following content:

```
public JPanelA(JPanel parent) {
    initComponents();
    this.parent = parent;
    run();
}

private void run() {
    jButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
        Main.getFrame().pack(); // nothing happens
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) parent.getLayout();
        cl.show(parent, Main.getPanel(1));
        //Main.getFrame().pack(); // neither anything happens
    });
}
```

The main logics is `JFrame` contains the main `JPanel cards` that is constructed with `CardLayout` and contains both `JPanelA a` and `JPanelB b`. `JPanelA a` is the starting one.

How to make to switch panels with their size, an not the maximum of their ones combined? And is this generally a good approach to start with `Java Swing` and the following appliactions?

Comment: This is how CardLayout works -- its preferredSize is the largest preferred size of all the "card" components that it holds.

Comment: I have found it. That's why I ask for a different way with a similar and simple approach that would change the size of JFrame as I wish.

Comment: `that would change the size of JFrame as I wish.` As a user we don't like the size of the frame to keep changing just because a different function is invoked. We like to size the frame appropriately for our desktop the way we work, not the way you think we should work.

Comment: @camickr Yes, I agree.. but how about a small login and register screen and a big window?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: for that I'd use a dialog window such as a JDialog. Either that or embed a login JPanel into a larger JPanel, perhaps one with a background image.